# How can I stop a jQuery Mobile table being responsive?

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, media-queries

I'm attempting to apply media queries to a table to hide optional columns on smaller devices.

I have two columns to hide based on two screen breaks:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 33em) {
  th.optional-1,
  td.optional-1 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 43em) {
  th.optional-2,
  td.optional-2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Then I apply `class="optional-1"` to both the `th` and `td` elements. I add `data-role="table"` to get the table to style correctly.

The media query works fine, however once the table gets to the default responsive size the table drops to a flattened view. I first thought about adding a class to force the table to be unresponsive (which works) but it then stops my optional classes working as both are competing with `!important` which is required to get over the default responsive style in JQM.

```
.table-responsive-none td,
.table-responsive-none th,
.table-responsive-none tbody th,
.table-responsive-none tbody td,
.table-responsive-none thead td,
.table-responsive-none thead th {
  display: table-cell !important;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.table-responsive-none td .ui-table-cell-label,
.table-responsive-none th .ui-table-cell-label {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Alternatively I could use `data-mode="columntoggle"` but I don't want the behaviour of the column toggling facility and I want to also specify my own breaks.

The problem is fixed when removing `data-role="table"` but then the table doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

Bugger if only I thought of this sooner.

I solved the problem by removing `data-role="table"` and adding the class `ui-table` to the table which now turns off responsive behaviour and lets me control it. In the end I only need the media queries to hide the columns at the given breaks.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 33em) {
  th.optional-1,
  td.optional-1 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 43em) {
  th.optional-2,
  td.optional-2 {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```